# Returning Modified Following business date while building Quarterly calendar

Tags: excel-2003

Trying to build a quarterly calendar of working business days (adjusted by holidays).

I am using =edate (A1,4), the only problem is that this function does not adjust for business days. Ideally I would wrap the formula using =workday(edate(A1,4),0,USD_Hols) but it seems that I cannot just add "0" for the formula to return the next business day.

Does anyone know how to get the next business day and also if next business day falls in the next month return the nearest previous business day?

Thanks
Paco

Comment: Our good friend JP has a post that might help: http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/get-previous-business-day-in-vba/

Comment: Thank you Doug for the reply, although this function does not seem to handle a given calendar of holidays like workday does, no? I need the function to take a given set of holidays...

Comment: You're right.  Actually I could use a little more info.  What's in A1?  What do you expect the formula to return relative?  Do you just want the last workday in each quarter, or all workdays?

Comment: A1 is a non-adjusted day (as in random day) the formula is supposed to return a business day after that day (holiday adjusted), except in the event that the next day falls on the following month in which case the formula should return previous biz day.

Comment: If A1 is a workday, does "previous work day" in your comment mean the date in A1, or the workday before the date in A1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works based on your description on comments.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "previous" in the comment.  Below, I'm assuming that it means A1, if A1 is a workday, or the workday before A1 if A1 is not a workday:

```
=IF(MONTH(WORKDAY(A1,1,USD_Hols))=MONTH(A1),WORKDAY(A1,1,USD_Hols),WORKDAY(WORKDAY(A1,1,USD_Hols),0-1,USD_Hols))
```

I haven't used workday functions much.  One thing I notice is that a 0 argument for days seems to return the date in A1 even if it's not a workday.  That's why I included the nested IFs in the ValueIfFalse part of the main IF.  It forces it to the next workday and then the one previous to that.

Comment: Managed with the help of a friend to create a vba function. Please see below: `Function NextBiz(d As Range, holidays As Range) As Date If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(d) = 7 Or WorksheetFunction.Weekday(d) = 1 Or WorksheetFunction.CountIf(holidays, d) > 0 Then NextBiz = WorkDay(d, 1, holidays) Else NextBiz = d End If End Function `

Answer (score 0):

You must add the worksheetfunction to the Workday to Excel 2010

This is correct:

```
Function NextBiz(d As Range, holidays As Range) As Date
    If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(d) = 7 Or WorksheetFunction.Weekday(d) = 1 Or WorksheetFunction.CountIf(holidays, d) > 0 Then
    NextBiz = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(d, 1, holidays)
    Else: NextBiz = d
    End If
End Function
```